# minimum function on a set

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima

How to find the minimum $x+y+z$ on the following set $ (x-2)^{2}+(y-2)^{2}+(z-2)^{2} \le 1 ? $ is it $1$? I am just guessing some of the points $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$. I have no clue how to solve these examples.

Comment: You should edit the question to add your attempt for a good response.

Comment: @Laura  Show please your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: @Laura I have found a mistake in my first solution and posted something new. Show more  attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f (x,y,z)=x+y+z $

$(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2 \leq 1$ spans a sphere which has a center C(2,2,2)

$f_x (x,y,z)=f_y (x,y,z)=f_z (x,y,z)=1 \gt 0$ that means f is increasing so

x < a, y <b , z<c $\Rightarrow f (x,y,z) < f (a,b,c) $

If there exists a point O which makes f minimum it must be close to smaller values as much as possible so the point P is on the  $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2=1$

That is important because we can use Lagrange's method now

Let $g (x,y,z)=(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2 - 1=0$ then  there exists a scalar k which makes
$\nabla f (x,y,z)= k \nabla g(x,y,z) $ for point P (x,y,z)
$1=(2x-2)k$

$1=(2y-2)k$

$1=(2z-2)k$

$2x-2=2y-2=2z-2  \Rightarrow  x=y=z $

$3(x-2)^2=1$ $ \Rightarrow  x=2-\frac {1}{\sqrt (3)} $

$f(x,y,z)=6-\sqrt (3) $

Comment: The first part seems to be for me quite complicated to understand. The second part is clear. I used Lagrange function in this way $L=x+y+z +\lambda [(x-2)^{2}+(y-2)^{2}+(z-2)^{2}-1]$ and it works as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did the same actually but first i proved that i can use it

Comment: is the function $f(x,y,z)$ correct? $x+y+z(x-2)^{2}$ seems to be wrong.

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ i  forgot to put a space between equation and inequality

Answer (score 0):

For $x=y=z=2-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ we obtain the value $6-\sqrt3$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, $$\sum_{cyc}\left(x-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(x-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\left(x-2)^2-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\left(1-\sum_{cyc}(x-2)^2\right)=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(x-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\left(1-\sum_{cyc}(x-2)^2\right)\geq0$$

Comment: Well, how you know it will be $x=y=z=2-\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}$?

Comment: @Laura Show please your attempts. If you don't make it, this topic may be deleted, but I don't want that my solution would be deleted. Do it please.

Comment: @Laura Now it's really not fair, that you don't want to show your attempts.

Comment: @Laura I solved this problem without software and I am ready to explain any steps. Show your attempts and I'll explain.

Comment: @Laura I see at least more three solutions, by using vectors and else. I am ready to show. Show your attempts before.